# Multiple PHP ```for``` loops for MySQL Update

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a single column in a table but in order to do that I simply need 2 `for` loops. But the problem is that it doesn't happen.

Instead of getting something like this:

```
UPDATE sample_var set var_id="82" where id=195288

UPDATE sample_var set var_id="83" where id=195289

UPDATE sample_var set var_id="84" where id=195290

UPDATE sample_var set var_id="85" where id=195291
```

(I just `echo $sql;` to see what will I get)

I get this:

```
UPDATE sample_var set var_id="82" where id=195288

UPDATE sample_var set var_id="83" where id=195288

UPDATE sample_var set var_id="84" where id=195288

UPDATE sample_var set var_id="85" where id=195288
```

And when I execute the following statements the data just overwrites itself, leaving every updated row with the last value (In this case var_id=85 in every row).

Here is the block of code that I'm using for this particular case:

```
for($i=0;$i<$foo_count;$i++){

    for($a=0;$a<$bar_count;$a++){

       $update_SQL= 'UPDATE sample_var set var_id="'.$bar[$a][0].'" where id='.$foo[$i][0];

          DataBase::ExecuteStatement($update_SQL);

    }    

}
```

How can I avoid this kind of problem?

Thx in advance :D

Comment: why 2 loops if the second key is fixed?

Comment: $bar[$a][0] and $foo[$i][0] this will give you always same row. Why using static?

Comment: Because I'm pulling the data from  2 separate places, the first is array list that contains the data that I need to set (var_id=$data), and the second is the id of the row that needs to be updated, that is the reason of 2 loops

Comment: why not to use one array where key is id and value is var_id (or something similar) ?   array(195288=>82, 195289=>83, 195290=84.. etc) ? what if length of one array greater/less than the second one?

Comment: I can't merge it like that. $bar can be with max 20 inputs while $foo can be more than 500. If the first variable reaches its max it resets and starts from the begining while the second is going while it reaches its max and then the query ends (Example 12345=>1,12346=>2,12347=>1,12348=>2 etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this :

```
$bar = array('82','83','84','85');
$foo = array(195288,195289,195290,195291);

$bar_count = count($bar);
for($a=0;$a<$bar_count;$a++){

   $update_SQL= 'UPDATE sample_var set var_id="'.$bar[$a].'" where id='.$foo[$a];
  DataBase::ExecuteStatement($update_SQL);

}
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to answer by 4 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through every possible combination of $foo_count and $bar_count, which is why you are seeing the problem you described.

Assuming `$foo_count == $bar_count`, you can do this:

```
for($i=0; $i < $foo_count; $i++){

   $update_SQL= 'UPDATE sample_var set var_id="'. $bar[$a][0] .'" where id='. $foo[$i][0];

   DataBase::ExecuteStatement($update_SQL);

}
```

Comment: That is the problem :D 
$foo_count != $bar_count. $bar_count can be a max of 20 while $foo_count can go to 500. The point is that the data that is stored in $foo repeats itself (if the range is from 1 to 10, when it reaches then, the loop forces him to start all over, while the id continues going to its max value)

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<$foo_count;$i++){

       $update_SQL= 'UPDATE sample_var set var_id="'.$bar[$i][0].'" where id='.$foo[$i][0];

          DataBase::ExecuteStatement($update_SQL);   
}
```

One foreach loop is enough as $foo_count and $bar_count must be equal as per you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

My possible solution. then insert SQL instruction:

```
$bar = array("82","83","84","85");
$foo = array("195288","195289","195290","195291");
$updateValues = "";

for($i=0;$i<count($bar);$i++){
    $updateValues .= "UPDATE sample_var SET var_id='".$bar[$i]."' WHERE id='".$foo[$i]."';";
}
DataBase::ExecuteStatement($updateValues);
```